Cannot access groups in a NetCDF file from a YAML file
I have a YAML file in which I want to store the variables from a netCDF file and access the latter.
files:
  - path: "file.nc"
    variables:
      radiance: radiance
    groups:
      location:
        lon: lon

I am able to access radiance, but when I access location, i spits out the following error:
ERROR: LoadError: NetCDF error: Variable 'location' not found in file

The part of the code I am using to extract it:
struct GeosData
    data::Dict{String, Any}
end

function loadGeos(config_path::String)
    config = YAML.load_file(config_path)
    all_data = Dict{String, Any}()
    file_paths = [file_info["path"] for file_info in config["files"]]

    base_names = [split(filepath, ".") for filepath in file_paths]
    for i in 1:length(base_names) - 1
        @assert length(base_names[i]) == length(base_names[i + 1]) "Filenames have different lengths when split."
        for j in 1:length(base_names[i])
            if j != 2
                @assert base_names[i][j] == base_names[i + 1][j] "Filenames differ at component $j: $(base_names[i][j]) vs $(base_names[i + 1][j])"
            end
        end
    end

    for file_info in config["files"]
        file_path = file_info["path"]
        variables = file_info["variables"]
        groups = get(file_info, "groups", Dict{String, Any}())
        ds = NCDataset(file_path)

        for (file_var, internal_var) in variables
            all_data[internal_var] = ds[file_var][:]
        end

        for (group_name, group_vars) in groups
            group = ds[group_name]
            for (file_var, internal_var) in group_vars
                all_data[internal_var] = group[file_var][:]
            end
        end

        close(ds)
    end

    return GeosData(all_data)
end

geos_data = loadGeos("/Users/arpitasen/Documents/GitHub/EMIT-Caltech/src/EMIT.yaml")

radiance = geos_data.data["radiance"]
lon = geos_data.data["lon"]

println("Radiance data: ", radiance)
println("Longitude data: ", lon)

It is still treating "location" as a variable, how do i fix it?

What code are you running that produces that error? What are you doing to produce that YAML file? Can you please provide a minimal, reproducible example to help debug what is going on?

@PaSTE I have added the code

Thank you, but the code is both very verbose and yet not enough to reproduce the error: what is file.nc that you have listed in your example YAML file? The error suggests that it does not contain a variable called "location," but without being able to inspect that file, I cannot tell if you if this is because of a bug in the NetCDF library, an error in your YAML file, or if everything is working as intended and the NetCDF file is simply not what you expect it to be.
